# Is there a name for the "with-respect-to variable" of a partial derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

In a fraction $\dfrac{a}{b}$, a is called the numerator or dividend and b is called the denominator or divisor. These names are helpful when discussing an equation.

In a derivative or partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$, is there a common name for the variable $x$?

(i.e., "the variable that the derivative is computed with-respect-to")

Comment: It is just "with respect to $x$". If it happens that $x$ is the first variable then you could say "with respect to the first variable". I'm not sure I see what you are missing in the language, here. Could you insert this more into a context where you actually would like to say something that you don't know how to say?

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is the independent variable and $y$ depends on (or is a function of $x$). But if you're asking whether $\partial x$ has a name on it's own then that's a good question. My answer is I don't think there is such a name for it, although we refer to it as "partial x".

I think what is causing the problem here is the fact that derivatives are being represented as fractions:$\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, where $u$ is a function of two variables $x$ and $y$ or $u(x,y)$.

They don't need to be as $u_x \equiv \cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ where the subscript tells you which variable to differentiate with respect to. So the $x$ subscript has taken the role of the denominator of $\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

This is why they don't have a name because they don't need to have one; as the denominator just tells you which variable to differentiate with respect to, as does the $x$ subscript.

Comment: I used a/b as an example to explain my question. In y', you still have the problem of naming the thing/concept that y is being differentiated with respect to. I'm writing about various partial derivatives of a multivariate function. It seems that awkwardness could be reduced if those w.r.t variables had a proper name. It seems like the kind of thing that would have a name!

Comment: @Ben It's given in the context of an equation, i'll edit my post to show you

Comment: @Ben I wish you were right and they did have a name:) Maybe it's best to wait around for a while and see what the other users think about this. I'm sure someone can give you some more information on this.

Comment: @theonlygusti Yes it should, you are right. That was a typo, thanks